# How can wireless reception be improved for a particular device?

Tags: router, wireless-networking

To be clear this regards a situation where it is not feasible or possible to improve upon the WiFi router itself (transmission location has already been adjusted several times).

The recipient device (a Laptop) is in a secondary location (about 30-40 meters from the router) that is currently enjoying a sketchy reception.

Are there means to improve a recipient device's ability to receive a signal or would the only solution short of replacing the router be to introduce a bridge at some point? Kindly presume that both receiving and sending points are not in a position to get any closer to each other.

Thank you for any advice provided and do let me know if you feel that this question would have been better placed in another SE section.

Comment: Before you invest in a bridge, you might consider an external wireless adapter with an external antenna.  That might boost your reception a bit.

Comment: That certainly sounds like a plan worth looking into. Thanks for the comment Ron.

Comment: Please include model of device like Ron mentioned external antennas are the most popular method but not available for all equipment. there may also be specific bugs in your device etc.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the bridge you should be able to increase the tx power to help improve signal strength.  In addition a site survey may also help improve overall wirless performance be allowing you to identify any overlapping interference from other devices (I.e. other waps/wirless networks) . Improving signal for a single device would require extra equipment I.e. an AP as previously mentioned on the comments. I hope this helps

Comment: as well as a background noise issue.  some people have microwaves/refrigerators/motered equipment between or near the devices causing loss of signal. A proper survay would tell you what is putting out the noise.  there may be some free software to allow you to walk around with your laptop and find problems that way.